# nextcord Command isn't working when I use Global Variables in f-strings

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.id == (isohel): #the userID for the user isohel is saved in the variable "isohel"
        if f"@{bot}" in message.content: #the bots ID is saved in the variable bot.
            await message.reply("you pinged me")
```

^that is what i want my code to look like, so i can use the variable names instead of the userIDs so its easier to read incase of errors. However, this code does work.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.id == 476433240891195403: #the userID of the user "isohel"
        if "@1042552458175598642" in message.content: #the bots userID
            await message.reply("you pinged me")
```

i just want my code to be easy to read in case of errors in the future.

Comment: Which scope was `bot` defined in? There isn't one single global scope; every module has its *own* global scope.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this code that you gave me it worked so I think there may be a problem elsewhere. This was the code that I used. Try changing the variables to match yours then test this code. I'm not sure if you are using `nextcord` or `discord.py` but this is how it would work in `discord.py`:

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


MY_USER_ID = 
MY_BOT_ID = 
YOUR_PREFIX = ""
YOUR_TOKEN = ""
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(command_prefix=YOUR_PREFIX, intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.author.id == MY_USER_ID: #the userID of the user "isohel"
        if F"@{MY_BOT_ID}" in message.content: #the bots userID
            await message.reply("you pinged me")

client.run(YOUR_TOKEN)
```

It could be to do with your variables' names because `bot` can be used instead of `client` so there might have been some confusion.

Comment: i use nextcord, i tried to install pycord and discord.py and had many errors. @DRags

Comment: Can you explain those errors?